# Dynamic variable lead to error as it's not assigned correctly

Tags: linux, bash, variables, variable-assignment

Iam trying to build a little argument wrapper in other to progress in my bash capabilities and progress :)

With the below script block, I am struggling to assign correctly the arrays received as argument to a function.

```
#!/bin/bash

wrap (){
    while (( "${#}" )); do
        if [[ "${1}" == "--"* ]]; then
            option="${1/--/}"
            "${option}"="${@:2}"
            shift
        fi
        shift
    done
}

ARR_1=("Apple" "Orange" "Lemon")
ARR_2=("Onion" "Potato" "Carrot")

wrap --FRUITS ${ARR_1[@]} --VEGIES ${ARR_2[@]}
echo ${FRUITS[*]}
echo ${VEGIES[*]}
```

I get the following error

./function_collection.sh: line 8: FRUITS=Apple: command not found
./function_collection.sh: line 8: VEGIES=Onion: command not found

I tried different variable expansion such as `"${option}"="${!2}"` `"${option}"="{!$2}"` but with no succes either.

The variables in the wrapping function must be global so that's why I didnt tried with `declare`, `eval` or `local` commands

Comment: Note that when you leave out the quotes, `${array[@]}` becomes exactly identical to unquoted `${array[*]}`. **Always** quote `"${array[@]}"`

Comment: Also, the operation you're trying to perform here is called _indirect assignment_, and there's a lot of documentation available on how to do it well. In particular, see [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables)

Comment: ...indirect assignment _of arrays_ is trickier, and generally requires namevars (one of the better ways to do this ends up with `wrap --FRUITS ARR1 --VEGIES ARR2` and letting `wrap` do the job of the dereferencing as well as the assignment)

Comment: @Charles Duffy Your link about indirect assignment seems like a gold mine. I'll dig deeper and came back to you eventually. Thank you for your above advises. They're much appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current design is not correct, try it with echo:

```
wrap (){
    while (( "${#}" )); do
        if [[ "${1}" == "--"* ]]; then
            option="${1/--/}"
            echo "${@:2}"
            shift
        fi
        shift
    done
}

$ wrap --FRUITS ${ARR_1[@]} --VEGIES ${ARR_2[@]}
Apple Orange Lemon --VEGIES Onion Potato Carrot
Onion Potato Carrot
```

It should be like this:

```
wrap2 (){
    while (( "${#}" )); do
        if [[ "${1}" == "--"* ]]; then
            option="${1/--/}"
            shift
        fi
        echo $option $1
        shift
    done
}

$ wrap2 --FRUITS ${ARR_1[@]} --VEGIES ${ARR_2[@]}
FRUITS Apple
FRUITS Orange
FRUITS Lemon
VEGIES Onion
VEGIES Potato
VEGIES Carrot
```

And to create arrays you cat use `printf` hack:

```
wrap3 (){
    while (( "${#}" )); do
        if [[ "${1}" == "--"* ]]; then
            option="${1/--/}"
            i=0
            shift
        fi
        printf -v "$option[$i]" $1
        shift
        ((i++))
    done
}

$ wrap3 --FRUITS ${ARR_1[@]} --VEGIES ${ARR_2[@]}

$ echo ${FRUITS[@]}
Apple Orange Lemon

$ echo ${VEGIES[@]}
Onion Potato Carrot
```

Comment: Your workaround wourked out (specifically the 3rd spec) Thank you :)